# Can't generate pdf report in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, wkhtmltopdf

When i trying to print customer invoice getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/liveAMS/openerp/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 121, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter='pdf')
  File "/home/ubuntu/liveAMS/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/liveAMS/openerp/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 65, in report_routes
    pdf = report_obj.get_pdf(cr, uid, docids, reportname, data=options_data, context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/liveAMS/openerp/api.py", line 256, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/liveAMS/openerp/addons/report/models/report.py", line 198, in get_pdf
    save_in_attachment = self._check_attachment_use(cr, uid, ids, report)
  File "/home/ubuntu/liveAMS/openerp/api.py", line 256, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/liveAMS/openerp/addons/report/models/report.py", line 345, in _check_attachment_use
    pdf = base64.decodestring(pdf)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 321, in decodestring
   return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

Installed wkhtmltopdf: wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt).

How can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo might be trying to load an empty PDF from the database. In this case, try these:

1. Enable debug / developer mode - go to yoursite.com/web?debug
2. Go to Settings > Technical > Reports > Reports
3. Search for 'invoices'
4. Click on the report record with name `Invoices` and Template Name `account.report_invoice`
5. Click **Edit**
6. Uncheck `Reload from attachment`
7. Click **Save**

Now try to print the invoice again.

Comment: Thank you Abu, it works.Could you explain why should i uncheck `Reload from attachment`, because in my local instance its working fine without uncheck the same.

Comment: `Reload from attachment` is a function that speeds up the printing process in Odoo, so that instead of re-creating a document everytime it needs to be printed, Odoo just saves the file as an attachment and loads it when you click **Print**. There is probably an empty file attached to the record for some reason, so when you click **Print** it tries to load the empty file and hence the error. When you uncheck `Reload from attachment`, it forces Odoo to recreate the attachment everytime you click **Print**.

Comment: You can now go back to the settings and check `Reload from attachment` again so that you can use this handy functionality in Odoo.

Comment: Now i again check 'Reload from attachment` to `True`, and its working fine without any error.

Comment: Glad I could help!